# Can you get all entities of a model in appengine and not a gqlquery

Tags: google-app-engine, model, gql

I want a list of all my model entities. Model.all() returns a gqlquery. I know that I can then do list comprehension on the query and end up with the result I am seeking. Is there not a way already built-in saving the additional step of doing the comprehension?

Or is everyone just subclassing and building the method in themselves?
... or is this a safety measure preventing us from accessing more data then we intended incurring costs?

Thanks

Comment: Actually, `Model.all()` returns a `Query`, not a `GqlQuery`.

Answer (score 1):

To get to the entity you need a key. If you only have a kind of the entity, then GAE needs to go through indexes to find all keys, e.g. it uses [Metadata Queries](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/metadataqueries.html).

Metadata queries give you the option to query by namespace, kind and property.

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 options:

- use fetch() and get a defined number of entities like Model.all().fetch(100)
- use Model.all() and loop over the query.

Comment: Iterating over the query (as the OP suggests) is a bad idea - it'll result in multiple fetch operations, instead of just one.