# Retrive all the entities from a datastore

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, low-level-api

I m using the low-level API in the App Engine Datastore . To retrieve an entity I use

```
Entity post = datastore.get(postKey);
```

but this code will return only the post with this postkey. What shall i do if i want to return all the posts ?

Comment: did you checked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9824317/can-you-get-all-entities-of-a-model-in-appengine-and-not-a-gqlquery or http://stackoverflow.com/a/6529915/529543 , did you searched in your seach engine??

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list kinds in datastore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2541945/how-to-list-kinds-in-datastore)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need todo a query, not a get,

get ist just a single instance by id,
query is result of your query.

just do:

```
// Use class Query to assemble a query
Query q = new Query("Post");

// Use PreparedQuery interface to retrieve results
PreparedQuery pq = datastore.prepare(q);


for (Entity result : pq.asIterable()) {
  String postName = (String) result.getProperty("PostName");
}
```

Comment: In 2019, it's not working anymore.